# How to use Markdown in Elm: is it [markdown| or [markdown |?

Tags: markdown, elm

Here is my code snippet: http://www.share-elm.com/sprout/53d242e2e4b07afa6f9834a2 inspired by elm-lang.org's [example](http://elm-lang.org/edit/examples/Elements/Markdown.elm).

```
main : Element
main = flow down
  [ [markdown| #Hello World |]
  , [markdown| The quick **brown** box *jumps* over the lazy dogs. |]
  ]
```

I am familiar with markdown itself, as on [Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) or [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) itself.  However, I have several questions about how Markdown is used from within Elm.  I could not find the documentation for Elm's

- What does `[markdown|` mean?  Why is `[markdown |` - notice the space - not acceptable?
- Why does `#Hello World` not appear big?  It should appear large like this

## Hello World

---

Here's is a corrected example, but I don't know what I did right.

```elm
main : Element
main = flow down
  [ [markdown|
  
# Hello World 
  
  |]
  , [markdown| The quick **brown** box *jumps* over the lazy dogs. |]
  ]
```

---

Using strings seems to also be wrong, as in `[markdown| "# Hello World" |]`.  Why is this wrong?

I thought it would be safer to remind Elm that my sentence was a string, but it seems I don't have to.  And shouldn't.

Comment: In your first example, everything after the `#` is part of the header. The parser doesn't recognize the `|]` on that line as the end of the quasiquotation.

Comment: @Joe Are the `[|` and `|]` called **quasiquotes** ?  I couldn't find them in the elm [syntax](http://elm-lang.org/learn/Syntax.elm).

Comment: Yes. As far as I'm aware, they come from the Haskell syntax for them: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Quasiquotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `[|` and `|]` is syntax that was borrowed from Haskell. These are called quasiquotes and take a literal name between the first `[` and `|`. Elm currently support [markdown](http://elm-lang.org/blog/announce/0.4#markdown-support) through this mechanism, and [GLSL](https://github.com/elm-community/elm-webgl#writing-shaders) for the [WebGL library](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/elm-webgl/latest).
I think the [original announcement](http://elm-lang.org/blog/announce/0.4) is the only documentation for now, we should definitely ask for the [Syntax reference page](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax) to include how to use markdown.

As for your example use: The problem with the header "Hello World" does not come from the single-line use, but from the leading space. This code gives the desired behaviour:

```
main : Element
main = flow down
  [ [markdown|#Hello World|]
  , [markdown|The quick **brown** box *jumps* over the lazy dogs.|]
  ]
```

This is normal behaviour for markdown IIRC:

#Hello World
(^ has a leading space)

Comment: The problem with Markdown is that it has so many flavors! For instance, now on GitHub you *have to* include a space between `#` and `Hello World`